Python script to renumber slide ids inside a pptx presentation
Intro
I have never had the patience or the free time to really read a python book from cover to cover.  I just starting coding, looking up things and pasting stuff.  That was ok because I was the sole consumer of my ugly hacks.  But, a few days ago, I ran into an issue and hacked my way out through yet another "tool".  However, this time, things were a bit different because I thought that tool could be useful to others running into the same issue. So, I posted it as my first github "gist".  Then I thought "Wait! What if that stuff does more harm than good" and "maybe, how can I make it more decent".  Responsibility crisis.  Good opportunity to submit my first question here too. Thx in advance for the time and support.
The issue
Recently, I ran into an annoying issue: in some of my powerpoint presentations, powerpoint refused to add more slides.  No add, no insert, no duplication. zilch.
Then later, while generating some pptx through python-pptx, I ran into an error message:

ValueError: value must be in range 256 to 2147483647 inclusive, got
2147483648

That was an eye opener for me.  My pptx templates were hitting the max slide id.  That's what happens when your company is producing 1000s of slide decks per day.
Code
So I waited for the week end and coded the hack below.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import traceback
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED
import lxml.etree as ET


xslt_src = """<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    >
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="mapping" match="/p:presentation/p:sldIdLst/p:sldId" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/p:presentation/p:sldIdLst/p:sldId">
        <p:sldId id="{256 + count(key('mapping', @id)/preceding-sibling::*)}" r:id="{@r:id}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- reuse same new ids in sections -->
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='sldId' and not (name()=p:sldId)]">
        <p:sldId id="{256 + count(key('mapping', @id)/preceding-sibling::*)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>"""


def parse_arguments():
    """
        Purpose: parse and return all arguments
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Extracts slide Ids from a pptx Powerpoint presentation'
    )
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input',  help='Powerpoint input file',  dest='input',  required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Powerpoint output file', dest='output', required=True)

    return parser.parse_args()


def read_zip(file_name):
    bio = BytesIO(open(file_name, 'rb').read())
    archive = ZipFile(bio, 'r')
    content = {n: archive.read(n) for n in archive.namelist()}
    archive.close()

    return content


def write_zip(file_name, content):
    bio = BytesIO()
    archive = ZipFile(bio, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for name, data in content.items():
        archive.writestr(name, data)
    archive.close()
    open(file_name, 'wb').write(bio.getvalue())


def reset_slide_ids(content):
    input_dom = ET.fromstring(content['ppt/presentation.xml'])
    transformer = ET.XSLT(ET.fromstring(xslt_src))
    content['ppt/presentation.xml'] = ET.tostring(transformer(input_dom), encoding='utf-8')

    return content


def main():
    """
    The main sequence of calls
    :return:
    """
    try:
        args = parse_arguments()
    except Exception:
        print("Error parsing command line")
        traceback.print_exc()
        return

    try:
        write_zip(args.output, reset_slide_ids(read_zip(args.input)))
    except Exception:
        print("Error rewriting zipfile")
        traceback.print_exc()
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

RFC
I'm especially interested in

The python part: how to make this more "pythonic".
The XSLT.  There are a few hacks here (like dodging dynamic namespaces or creating a sequence).  Maybe you guys know better.
The OpenXML compliance.  I didn't research that at all. Just dumped stuff into Sublime,  indented, and made some assumptions.  So, venturing bare foot into the OpenXML minefield, more or less.


binary I/O
This is weird:
    bio = BytesIO(open(file_name, 'rb').read())
    archive = ZipFile(bio, 'r')

Better to just say archive = ZipFile(file_name) and be done with it.
There are good reasons for passing in a bytes buffer,
but this isn't one of them.
context manager
    archive = ZipFile(bio, 'r')
    content = {n: archive.read(n) for n in archive.namelist()}
    archive.close()

Prefer to use with so you get auto-close, even in the presence of exceptions:
    with ZipFile(file_name) as archive:
        content = {n: archive.read(n) for n in archive.namelist()}

meaningful docstring
In def main(), the docstring adds no value for future maintainers.
Simply elide it.
pointless try
There's no value-add here:
    try:
        args = parse_arguments()
    except Exception:
        print("Error parsing command line")
        traceback.print_exc()
        return

Nor here:
    try:
        write_zip( ... )
    except Exception:
        print("Error rewriting zipfile")
        traceback.print_exc()
        return

These are exception "handlers" that don't quite handle the exception.
Maybe in the land of java's checked exceptions such code would make sense.
Here it would be better to just write a pair of lines and let exceptions
bubble up the call stack to where they'll be reported to the end user:
    args = parse_arguments()
    write_zip(args.output, reset_slide_ids(read_zip(args.input)))


All good points. Thanks. Yes I saw that ZipFile was now a context manager (since 3.2). I also thought of using a walker (like indeed in Java, good guess). Docstring is from my boilerplate template and yes it's useless, Also agree with bio. Will correct all this asap.

I'm not qualified to review the "meat" of the program.  But I did notice that when we catch an exception in main(), we simply return without communicating that failure in the exit status of the program.  It would be better to sys.exit() with the message instead.  That also has the advantage that it writes to the standard error stream rather than standard output.
I'm not convinced of the value of printing the exception trace.  It might be useful for developers, but I'd probably make that conditional on a command-line option.  For normal users, it should be enough to simply show the exception's message.
Speaking of command-line options, we write:

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Extracts slide Ids from a pptx Powerpoint presentation'
    )


But it appears that it does more than extracting ids - doesn't it also write an output file?

Yes. Cut and paste mistake. Thanks.

As regards the XSLT, I think my main criticism would be
not (name()=p:sldId)
Which means not (name()=child::p:sldId). I think you probably intended
not (name()='p:sldId')
but that would be bad practice since it's matching the namespace prefix, not the URI. Better is not(self::p:sldId). (Having said that, I've no idea what this template rule is trying to achieve).
Some XSLT processors might give better performance by using xsl:number rather than counting preceding siblings, but I've no idea if that's true of the processor you are using.

Good catch. I needed the quote indeed.  MS Powerpoint dynamically generates as many namespaces as the presentation has sections.  Since you can't know what these are at coding time, you rewrite these sections in a non namespace-aware way. But you avoid rewriting the initial occurrence which also needs the r:ids attributes. Thanks Michael.
